# Classpath issue in play framework

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I sometimes move my source files from one package to another during refactoring. After I move them, Eclipse with play plugin cannot find the classes. I have to manually fix each and every import statement, instead of letting eclipse take care of it for me. For a large project, this takes a **lot of time**.

Also, each time I add a jar file to `/lib` Eclipse cannot find it even though it is added to the classpath.

The only solution I found is to delete the whole project, exit eclipse, "re-eclipsify" the play project, restart eclipse and reimport the project. After that it works again until I need to move some files around or add jars.

Is there a way to fix this classpath issue in Eclipse with Play? Regularly going through this whole re-eclipsification process is not very convenient.

Edit: also have the same problem with constant variables. Eclipse or play caches them and it's impossible to change them unless a whole re-eclipsification takes places.

Comment: have you tried to "eclipsify" and refresh teh project? Without deleting it.

Comment: try crtl+shft+O or in sorce menu there is a organise imports.Do this at the package level.It will organize all your imports which are unique.But for the package name refactoring in the class you must do it manually or by replace functions (using ctr + H) in file search

Comment: @Sanjay Jain I've tried ctrl-shft-o but that is exactly what doesn't work. if I manually add the import statements, Eclipse does find the classes. In other projects, I can just drag and drop classes to other packages, and all the import statements are automatically updated :/

Answer (score 1):

You can always add jars manually to the eclipse-projekt. You don't need to use play eclipsify.

If you move classes with the refactor functionality from eclipse, eclipse adjust all Java-Sources. In routes.conf and in the views it's a manual job, except you let eclipse search for text in this files.